# Is Programmers.SE suddenly going to be flooded with old, unwanted, two year old questions from StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

Example here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/as-a-programmer-what-single-discovery-has-given-you-the-greatest-boost-in-product

***Really?***

Comment: Please, explain your concern.

Comment: @bigown: My concern is that, now that the migration option is available, the SOPedians who have so desperately wanted to get rid of the "Best Programmer Cartoon" questions (and their ilk) now have a way to do so by migrating them here, without further review, without considering the charter of PSE, and without further appeal (you can't reverse a migration). The examples I've seen so far have been migrated by a *single moderator vote,* and closed here with a single moderator vote. Not exactly a community-friendly process, is it?

Comment: I agree.. Why allow migration of a post which is immediately deemed  "not constructive" and closed? It just becomes noise. I've been sucked into several of these questions recently, and it's become very annoying.

Answer (score 6):

My concern is that it has no value (doesn't meet the 6 guidelines) and thus I've voted to close it.

The thing that concerns me more is that the 15-20 questions that I've come across that have been migrated from SO also have little value to PSE.  They've either been dups or just a waste of breath.

Comment: I totally agree with this concern, but what it has to do with the fact the question has 2 year old?

Comment: @bigown - really, it has nothing to do with its age.  The age of a migrated question doesn't bother me, it's the value (or lack of) that is important.

Comment: I don't have an issue with duplicates - they help searches uncover information faster, as descibed in [this blog post.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a flood. The worst part is that they have the vote counts from SO intact, making them look more important and popular than they really are.

The ratings of the questions should either be scaled or, when migrated, should get a completely fresh count.

Comment: Vote counts are a reliable indicator of how popular a question is; zeroing them out is revisionist history.

Comment: @Robert: Think about it, it's a reliable indicator on SO. It's completely off our scales here. If they are good, they will get the upvotes and views.

Comment: I might agree with that point of view if a copy of the original question stayed on StackOverflow (thus preserving the counts history), but it doesn't.

Comment: @Robert - I think I'm leaning towards Macneil's point.  In theory we can have a SO question migrated to PSE with loads of votes and no one from PSE adds to the values.  That leaves a question (and answers) on PSE without any PSE users voting and yet it has some importance because SO users voted for it.  That's pretty messy.

Comment: What happens to the rep? Many of those questions have hundreds of votes - do those people now have thousands of rep on P.se? Do they lose that rep on SO?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I have been deleting the questions that I think have no lasting value.

The only ones I want migrated are the ones that are *useful*.

See:
[Set up an archive for legendary deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/set-up-an-archive-for-legendary-deleted-questions)

Comment: I wish the other members do it the same.