# Why is this question too old to be moved?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, declined-flags

A while ago I flagged [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85339/how-to-describe-your-skill-levels-in-the-cv) to be moved to the [Workplace beta](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), because it seems like a very good fit there, and it continues to get a lot of views. The flag was rejected because the question is too old. I don't think this is a good reason in this case, because, like I said, the question continuos to get a lot of views, and thus could be a great support for an upcoming StackExchange site. I realize that Programmers once had the problem of [old questions being migrated from Stackoverflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/820/is-programmers-se-suddenly-going-to-be-flooded-with-old-unwanted-two-year-old), but again, I think Workplace could benefit from this question.

Sure, I could just ask the question again there, but wouldn't it also be good for Programmers to have the question moved away, so as not to confuse new users about the topic of this site?

I guess in the end this is a request to rethink the decision and maybe still move the question.

Answer (score 11):

[Migration for questions older than 60 days is disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) (even for mods). It's not that we don't want to move it, we can't.

If you feel it's a good question for the Workplace, you should re-ask it there (but please search for existing duplicates first).

Comment: Also, I think it's worth mentioning that closed questions are still viewable and can still be helpful to future visitors, as long as they're not deleted.